# C++11 Aggregates & constructors speed comparison

Tags: performance, c++11, constructor, comparison, aggregate

How does the speed of the **default constructor**, the **copy constructor** and the **move constructor** compare to each other for an **aggregate** type like `std::array` that stores built-in type elements ?

Intuitively, I would say **move > default > copy** (the greater the faster).

Is that correct ?

Comment: It depends on the type of elements stored in the `array`. Could be move = default = copy, or move = copy > default or any combination.

Comment: You're right. I was actually thinking about built-in types. I'm correcting for that in my question.

Comment: Well move = copy for a builtin, so copy/move is the same as a memcpy equivalent and default is a memset equivalent (possibly SIMD, etc). Never mind I lied, default is not a memset it's just uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **default** constructor of a `std::array` holding a built-in (such as `float`, `int`, etc.) would be the fastest, followed by **move** and **copy** (which would be equivalently fast).

`std::array` is an aggregate so the **default** constructor doesn't do anything. As stated on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/)

> note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T

Notice that since these are built-ins, move and copy are entirely the same performance wise, since you can't move a built-in any faster than copying it.

So for a `std::array`, the ordering is **default** > **move** == **copy**.

This does not necessarily hold for aggregates that hold non built-ins, but does hold for aggregates that only hold built-ins or other aggregates that hold only built-ins.